# Implement right click functionality in pyvista

Tags: python, pyvista

I'm wondering whether its possible to add some functionality to a right click event in Pyvista. I am currently adding lines to a mesh starting from a certain point and ending on the point where i have clicked using `plotter.enable_point_picking(callback=callback, left_clicking=True)`. I now want to remove the line if the clicked point was not correct by using the right mouse button. I thought it would be as easy as creating a new callback for and setting `right_clicking=True` but then you get the error `Picking is already enabled, please disable previous picking with` disable_picking()` and from that point i have no clue how to fix it.

Could anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance